# What are the arguments for innatism, essentialism, and rationalism?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, philosophy-of-language, philosophy-of-logic

How do people justify some existents being absolutely necessary.

Why cant it just be against a backdrop of a relative nothingness?

How can someone justify certain ideas being absolutely essential and primitive like so

Wouldnt it just reduce to a state of no concepts at all if we were looking for the most basic thing?

Comment: Wouldn't the concept "the most basic thing" still be a relatively positive concept, or involve this (the concept of being basic, say)? Or wouldn't the concept of justification itself serve such a role?

Comment: @Kristian i see your point. but id wager that it hs a negative connotation as well. from the concept of lets say not being basic. and of all concepts which are not justification.

Comment: You might find [basic justification logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification/#BasJusLogMat) interesting: "J0
  is the logic of general (not necessarily factive) justifications for an absolutely skeptical agent for whom no formula is provably justified, i.e., J0
 does not derive t:F
 for any t
 and F
. Such an agent is, however, capable of drawing *relative justification conclusions*..."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Kristian im not versed enough to work out all the implications for this. do you mean to say it is not something that can be doubted?

Comment: @GeraldRobertson every proposition can begin with being doubted, but if we continued to doubt everything, this would nullify the doubt/belief distinction, and then what is the point of doubting anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, when I talk 'possible worlds' here, I mean 'a complete and consistent way the world is or could have been', the 'world' more meaning reality itself here.

There are no possible worlds in which there is nothing. If so, as nothingness is, in its name, not a thing and so not a thing that can exist, then either the nothingness exists and so the possible world does, which it cannot, or the possible world in which there is nothingness cannot exist. Therefore, the property of existence is necessary. A possible world of nothingness is a thing, so that possible world cannot exist.

This existence could be the 'most basic thing', as you call it, but I don't see why that most basic thing isn't something necessary.